# Warning: Permanently added '111.222.33.40' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts

Tags: server, ssh, rsync

While I run rsync command to copy one directory from one server to another I get this warning: **Warning: Permanently added '111.222.33.40' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts**.
The command looks like:

```
rsync -avz /root/custom-scripts  root@111.222.33.40:/root/
```

Why this command produces this warning? What it exactly means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` is using `ssh` under the hood, and this is a normal informational message from `ssh` when the remote host has not been encountered before. From `man ssh`:

> ```
>  ssh automatically maintains and checks a database containing identifica‐
>  tion for all hosts it has ever been used with.  Host keys are stored in
>  ~/.ssh/known_hosts in the user's home directory.  Additionally, the file
>  /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts is automatically checked for known hosts.  Any
>  new hosts are automatically added to the user's file.  If a host's iden‐
>  tification ever changes, ssh warns about this and disables password
>  authentication to prevent server spoofing or man-in-the-middle attacks,
>  which could otherwise be used to circumvent the encryption.
> ```

Comment: Ok thanks for help.